# Custom Formset validation errors not fired

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I created a custom validation error and it worked just fine before abstracting my class based views. For some reason, whenever there's an error, the error is just blank, e.g `[{}]`

Validation Error logic:

```
class BaseFormSetValidation(BaseModelFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()    
        days = ['day_1', 'day_2', 'day_3', 'day_4', 'day_5', 'day_6', 'day_7']
        for form in self.forms:
            for day in days:
                current_day = form.cleaned_data.get(day)
                if current_day is not None and current_day > 24:
                    raise ValidationError([{day: ["Submitted hours per day cannot exceed 24 hours"]}])


class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
        def __str__(self):
            return self.as_divs()
        def as_divs(self):
            if not self: return ''
            return '%s' % ''.join([e for e in self])

TimesheetModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Timesheet, formset=BaseFormSetValidation, exclude=("year", "week", "project", "user"), extra=0)
```

`TemplateView Class`

```
class TimesheetEditorView(BaseTimesheet, TemplateView):
    form_class = TimesheetModelFormSet
    template_name = "timesheets/timesheet.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        timesheet = Timesheet.objects.filter(year=context["year"], week=context["week"], user=self.request.user).order_by("project_id") 

        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(queryset=timesheet, error_class=DivErrorList)
        create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(self.request.user)

        context.update(
            timesheet=timesheet,
            timesheet_formset=timesheet_formset,
            create_timesheet_form=create_timesheet_form
        )
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if timesheet_formset.is_valid():
            messages.info(request, "Weekly timesheet updated", extra_tags='timesheet')
            timesheet_formset.save()
            success_url = reverse("timesheets:current-week", args=(context["year"], context["week"]))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
```

Which inherits from

```
class BaseTimesheet(object):

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseTimesheet, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week
        user = self.request.user


        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)
        calc_full_week = self.calc_full_week(year, week)

        context.update(
            week=week,
            year=year,
            next_week=next_week,
            previous_week=previous_week,
            next_year=next_year,
            previous_year=previous_year,
            current_week=calc_full_week
        )


        return context
```

And the template with error handling:

```
    {% for row in timesheet_formset %}
    {% if row.errors %}
    <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            Error on project {{ row.instance.project }}
            {% endif %}


            {% for field in row %}
            {% if field.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p>{{ field.label }} - {{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if row.errors %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% if timesheet_formset.non_form_errors %}
    <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            {{ timesheet_formset.non_form_errors }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Do I need to pass in `error_class=DivErrorList` elsewhere? Right now, whenever an error occurs, the form just "resets" so to say

This is what `TimesheetEditorView`looked like before my refactor and where the errors would be output correctly in the template. No actual "change" to the logic has happened - all I tried to do was refactor the code so my view wouldn't be so "thick"

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TimesheetEditorView(View):
    form_class = TimesheetModelFormSet

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week
        user = request.user
        if invalid_week(week, year):
            raise Http404("Invalid week / year")

        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)
        calc_full_week = self.calc_full_week(year, week)

        timesheet = Timesheet.objects.filter(year=year, week=week, user=user).order_by("project_id")  # only show timesheet rows that belongs to logged in user

        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(queryset=timesheet)
        create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(user)
        context = {
            "create_timesheet_form": create_timesheet_form,
            "timesheet_formset": timesheet_formset,
            "week": week,
            "year": year,
            "next_week": next_week,
            "next_year": next_year,
            "previous_week": previous_week,
            "previous_year": previous_year,
            "current_week": calc_full_week,
        }

        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week

        if invalid_week(week, year):
            raise Http404("Invalid week / year")

        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)

        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList)
        if timesheet_formset.is_valid():
            messages.info(request, "Weekly timesheet updated", extra_tags='timesheet')
            timesheet_formset.save()
            success_url = reverse("timesheets:current-week", args=(year, week))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

        create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(request.user)

        context = {
            "create_timesheet_form": create_timesheet_form,
            "timesheet_formset": timesheet_formset,
            "week": week,
            "year": year,
            "next_week": next_week,
            "next_year": next_year,
            "previous_week": previous_week,
            "previous_year": previous_year,

        }

        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", context)
```

Comment: has the exact same `raise ValidationError...` worked before? what do you mean by  "abstracting my class based views"

Comment: I'll update my question with what the `TimesheetEditor` class looked like before (and where `DivErrorList` worked fine)

Comment: Any idea, @bb4L?

Comment: inheritance: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-python/
let the `BaseTimeSheet` be a `TemplateView` and then the `TimeSheetEditor` only inherits from the `BaseTimeSheet`

Comment: What difference does that make

Comment: sorry doesn't make a real difference but would be nicer inheritance wise i guess....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't handing the form over:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    timesheet_formset = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if timesheet_formset.is_valid():
        messages.info(request, "Weekly timesheet updated", extra_tags='timesheet')
        timesheet_formset.save()
        success_url = reverse("timesheets:current-week", args=(context["year"], context["week"]))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
```

There is no need to call the `self.get_context_data(**kwargs)` with the same kwargs they will be the same. And you have to hand over the `timesheet_formset` and `create_timesheet_form` as you did in the "original" view.

This would result in something like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    timesheet_formset = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if timesheet_formset.is_valid():
        messages.info(request, "Weekly timesheet updated", extra_tags='timesheet')
        timesheet_formset.save()
        success_url = reverse("timesheets:current-week", args=(context["year"], context["week"]))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    context['timesheet_formset'] = timesheet_formset
    create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(request.user)
    context['create_timesheet_form '] = create_timesheet_form 

    return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", )
```

You have to test if you need both `timesheet_formset` and `create_timesheet_form`.

Comment: I've been scratching my head for the last two days trying to get it to work by just adding
` create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(request.user)` and `context['timesheet_formset'] = timesheet_formset` 
God I hate django sometimes. Thanks a lot for your help!